Mysql wp_postmeta table getting huge with WooCommerce Orders
I have a WooCommerce site with a large number of orders and users, which has led to the wp_postmeta table growing significantly in size. What are the best practices or methods to safely reduce the size of the wp_postmeta table without affecting the functionality of the site? Specifically, I’m looking for ways to clean up unused metadata, optimize the table, or remove unnecessary entries that might be slowing down the database.
Any suggestions or SQL queries to help with this would be appreciated!


If not done yet, you should try to switch to High Performance Order Storage (HPOS) that is now enabled by default in WooCommerce.

Thanks i'll try it will it reduce database size?

You need first to enable it in compatibility mode… Then it will populate progressively WooCommerce custom related tables (If you have many orders it can take some time, be patient). Once completed, you need to check first that plugins and custom code are compatible with HPOS (meaning not using anymore post and postmeta WordPress… See: WooCommerce HPOS related threads). Then when everything is OK, you can disable compatibility mode and you will be able to remove related WP postmeta data via WooCommerce > Status > Tools.

But make a DB backup first. This is a complex long sensitive process, for large database (your case). This will not reduce the database overall size, it will transfer orders data from WordPress tables to custom WooCommerce tables, lightening significantly post and postmeta tables, speeding up the backend.
